# Data recovery from deleted partitions in windows XP

Tags: windows, data-recovery

I accidentally deleted my whole 160 G hard disk while windows installation by pressing D, I lost all my data in drives D and E.

I then installed windows in that hard disk by creating partition of 40G, the rest of space was unformatted.

Now I created new partitions of that space (D, E, and F), I want to recover my old data, is there any way to get that data back? I have used recovery tool like Partition Recovery but it returns text, executables and Image files as corrupted files. Any help?

Comment: "I have used recovery tool like Partition Recovery but it returns text, executables and Image files as corrupted files".
is that same data  which you have lost due to accidentally deletion and now showing as corrupted (as you said ) or it is altogether different from original ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools for do this job. Some are paid and some are free. SO you have to choose which one is going to work for you.

[Recuva](http://www.recuva.com/) is freeware available. See more information about recuva on [lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5239099/hive-five-winner-for-best-free-data-recovery-tool-recuva).
[Active partiton](http://www.partition-recovery.com/) is another tool not free.
[GetDataBack](http://www.getbackdata.net/recover-data.html) is licensed version but works the best.
[DiskDigger](http://diskdigger.org/) is very tiny and free.